# How do we compare historical empires on these statistics?

Tags: political-history, colonization, nation-states, records, conquest

I see three criteria here:
I'm wondering which historical empire was the most long lived, largest, most populous, and represented the largest percentage of world population.

1. Who controlled the greatest amount land [highest estimate at the geographical peak of the empire]?
2. Who lasted the longest [highest estimate available]?
3. Who ruled the most people [highest estimate at population peak of the empire]?

   a. In terms of sheer numbers

   b. In terms of percentage of the total population of the world at the time.

Comment: 1) Russian Empire or Brittish Empire, depending on the definitions 2) Chineese Empire or Mongolia depending on definitions 3) Modern-day China, although India is pretty close

Comment: @Bregalad, your 2) is debatable. The Chinese state is divided into separate dynasties, which carry the corresponding name(e.g. Ming China, Qing China, etc.), and each change was followed by profound changes in society, government, economy(if the previous dynasty had worked, they wouldn't have dissapeared).
So my candidate would be the Brittish Empire, since, technically, it was one state at all times. 
And, as somewhat a funny and unusual candidate, i'd name the Bulgarian empire, the oldest country in Europe which keeps it's founding name to present day since it's creation(681 AC).

Comment: @Bregalad, and your 1) - really, no Mongols? The level of their control is certainly debatable, but their Empire was from the Sea of Okhotsk in the East to the Adriatic in the West, to the Persian Gulf in the South and the Arctic Ocean in the North.

Comment: @Adrian Todorov I absolutely agree, all this definitely **is** debatable. That's why I'm for closing this question. You get a point about Bulgaria but it was Ottoman for a very long time I'm not sure how many years but probably more than 500. Also I don't think modern Bulgaria would qualify as an "Empire".

Comment: I completely agree, it's mostly opinion based, since no reliable documents and sources exist from most of the times concerned, but there is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_empires) wiki article which tries to have a statistical approach.

Comment: @twosheds Can you tell that I haven't slept in a day and a half!

Comment: @WadCheber Oh and I forgot to mention Persia, aka Iran. It had existed and been independant for a **long** time too and would be a candidate for 2). I hope having those answers will allow you to finally fall asleep.

Comment: There's also the **Aztec** and **Inca** empires whose exact extent we're not sure of.

Comment: I think the Roman Empire should be a candidate for longest.  If you count the early kingdom & republic, it lasted from 753 BC (traditionally, anyway), up to the fall of Constantinople in 1453, or 2206 years.

Comment: @jamesqf Yeah, but the empire was separated in two so that does not count.

Comment: @Bregalad: Why not?  All those other empires gained or lost territory during their history - the British Empire, for instance, didn't end because it lost the US.  The Roman Empire had a continuous history through the span of its existence.

Comment: @Bregalad - Out of curiosity, how is this question opinion-based?  It asks for specific criteria- geographical range, total population, proportion of imperial population to global population, and longevity.  None of these things are opinion-based, they are all objective and factual.  Saying "My personal opinion is  that the Roman Empire was bigger than the British Empire" doesn't make sense.  Nor does "In my opinion, 500 million people is less than 60 million people", or "I feel like 200 years is longer than 100 years".

Comment: @WadCheber About the longevity it's the less subject to debate, but you saw in those comments, it depends if you count when an empire is split in two, if it  becomes absorbed by a bigger empire. For land, it depends if colonies count, or if very independant parts that have almost no political dependancy to the central power count. For population, in the antiquity there was no real records of how populated the empire were, for instance, slaves did not count as people, and probably made the majority of the population. I hope this clears up why this question isn't very well fitted for SE.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Wikipedia list of largest empires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_empires)?

Comment: This question is an opportunity to write an answer about the limitations of historical sources and **why** the answer is difficult.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Definitely, so I voted for re-opening.

Comment: What is the point of this exercise? I am asking in earnest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. largest area.  According to Wikipedia's list of largest empires, the largest thalassocracy or colonial empire was the British Empire about 1920 with 3.35 million square kilometers or 13.71 million square miles, 23.84 percent of the world's land area of 148,940,000 square kilometers or 57,500,000 square miles.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_empires[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_empires%5B1%5D)

2. longest lasting.  The first *Huang di* of China took the title in 211 BC and the last Qing dynasty *Huang di* was deposed in 1912.  Thus it can be calculated that the Chinese Empire lasted for 2,132 years.  But the major Chinese dynasties ended in bloody civil wars often resulting in many millions of deaths and fragmentation of the realm often lasting decades or centuries.   Thus it is hard to see government continuity between major dynasties, and it is common to refer to each major dynasty as a separate empire.

The Roman realm was a kingdom, republic, and empire lasted from sometime about the traditional foundation date of 753 BC, or the usual date of the foundation of the Empire in 27 BC, until the fall of the western Roman Empire in 476 or 480 AD (about 502, 506, 1,228, or 1,232 years), or the capture of Constantinople by the Fourth Crusade in 1204 (about 1230 or 1,956 years), or the capture of Constantinople by the Turks in 1453 (about 1,479 or 2,205 years), or the capture of the Morea by the Turks in 1460 (about 1,486 or 2,212 years), or the capture of Trebizond by the Turks in 1461 (about 1,487 or 2,213 years) or the fall of the Holy Roman Empire in 1806 (about 1,832 or 2,558 years).

See also here:

[http://www.eupedia.com/forum/threads/28700-Longest-lived-empires-states-in-history[2]](http://www.eupedia.com/forum/threads/28700-Longest-lived-empires-states-in-history%5B2%5D)

[http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-lasting-empire-in-history/[3]](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-lasting-empire-in-history/%5B3%5D)

[https://www.quora.com/Which-empire-lasted-the-longest-in-the-history[4]](https://www.quora.com/Which-empire-lasted-the-longest-in-the-history%5B4%5D)

[http://historum.com/general-history/70420-what-longest-lasting-empire-history.html[5]](http://historum.com/general-history/70420-what-longest-lasting-empire-history.html%5B5%5D)

3. a) Largest total population:

> By 1913, the British Empire held sway over 412 million people, 23% of the world population at the time,[2](http://www.eupedia.com/forum/threads/28700-Longest-lived-empires-states-in-history)

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Empire[6]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Empire%5B6%5D)

3. b) Largest percentage of the world's population:

Many sources say that the Achaemenid Empire in 480 BC ruled 44 percent of the world's population.  But that is disputed here, in post # 12.

[http://historum.com/general-history/126740-empire-ruled-largest-world-population.html[7]](http://historum.com/general-history/126740-empire-ruled-largest-world-population.html%5B7%5D)

Post number 16 gives more accurate figures for various realms including a more accurate (hopefully) list of the ten historical empires with the largest percentages of the world's population.

> 1. Qing (1800): 38-39%
> 2. Tang (750): 36%
> 3. Song (1100): 35%
> 4. Ming （1600）: 33%

> 5. Mongol Empire (1300): 29-30%

> 6. Han (1 CE): 29%
> 7. Sui (600): 29%

> 8. Republic of China (1915): 27%

> 9. Roman Empire (160): 26%
> 10. British Empire (1922): 25.5%

[http://historum.com/general-history/126740-empire-ruled-largest-world-population-2.html[8]](http://historum.com/general-history/126740-empire-ruled-largest-world-population-2.html%5B8%5D)

Answer (score -5):

I think the best empires were Spanish and Portuguese empire. Becuase they take long 300 years, they were the first european explorers and conquers of the world, and all with their technological limitations. The first empires that used the arquebus, the first firearm. XV- End of XVIII centuries their peak.

In contrast with the british empire and France empire, that they were the ones that continue the iberian empires. Ones making the best and the most advanced navy of the world. leading the industrial revolution  and the other having the best army of europe both in the end of XVIII.century. They started their empires using the musket that was the evolution of the Arquebus. End of XVIII-XIX. centuries their peak.

Germany, austria, Italy and Russia were the ones that were supposed to balance the power of the British and French in the world. Germans were the ones who achieved to build the best and most advanced army of europe just in the end of XIX. century, however, the lack of expand an empire outside europe limited with natural resources in their industry. These groups I considered as the  last modern european empires but had the limitations that UK and France didnt have. The end of XIX and early XX.century.

The XX.century is the century of the USA and Russia after ww1.

Comment: Does not answer it's question with the three arbitrary criteria proposed by OP.  OP did not ask about weapons.